# eslint not working in project generated by react-native init

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm having trouble getting eslint to work in react-native project generated by init

`npx react-native init Bar`

When I open eslint output in vscode I see this error

```
[Info  - 10:08:43 PM] ESLint server is starting
[Info  - 10:08:43 PM] ESLint server running in node v14.16.0
[Info  - 10:08:43 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 10:08:43 PM] ESLint library loaded from: /Users/myuser/Bar/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
[Info  - 10:08:43 PM] Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js » @react-native-community/eslint-config': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier' Require stack: - /Users/myuser/Bar/__placeholder__.js Referenced from: /Users/myuser/node_modules/@react-native-community/eslint-config/index.js
```

My system `OS: macOS 12.0.1 CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1`